# JavaScript new Date() with single param doesn't work as expected on Glitch

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working on a timestamp microservice on Glitch.me and have run into a problem when I pass a single number to the new Date() constructor. According to the docs, a single number is treated as milliseconds, but on Glitch it's a year:

```
 new Date(6546)
```

is automatically converted to "6546-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"

The actual code is:

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string", function(req, res) {
  let d = new Date(req.params.date_string);
  if (d == null || d == "Invalid Date") {
    res.json({
      unix: null,
      utc: "Invalid Date"
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      test: new Date(req.params.date_string),
      unix: d.getTime(),
      utc: d.toUTCString()
    });
  }
});
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: unless they overridden the default `new Date()` which i highly doubt, this shouldn't be happening. You are writting it in plain js, are you not? If so, then this indeed should return milliseconds from 1970. Search for a problem elsewhere perhaps

Comment: It is JS in Express app. My code is `app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string", function (req, res) {
  let d = new Date(req.params.date_string);
  
  if(d == null || d == "Invalid Date") {
      res.json({unix: null, utc: "Invalid Date"});
  } else {
    res.json({test: new Date(req.params.date_string), unix: d.getTime(), utc: d.toUTCString()});
  }  
});`

Comment: `console.log(req.params.date_string)` before you create a date please and give results back

Comment: console.log does return the number as it is. Then the problem is new Date(number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that When one **numeric argument** is passed in the constructor, it is taken as the internal numeric representation of the date in milliseconds,Note that **we are not passing a string** to the constructor. For example, passing the argument 5000 creates a date that represents five seconds past midnight on 1/1/1970.

For your case 6546 milliseconds which is 6.546 seconds will return the same date 1/1/1970, because there is no much difference when you add 5 seconds from that date.

but now if you pass "6546" milliseconds as a string to the constructor, it will be treated as year 6546 and you will get the output as 6546-01-01T00:00:00.000Z.
Check if you passing numeric value rather than string and if the value in millisecond is calculated correctly.
Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm

Try this codes for string and numeric arguments/values passed to the constructor respectively.

```
 console.log(new Date("6546").toLocaleDateString());
 console.log(new Date(6546).toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: Thank you, this insight helped a lot. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the name, I suspect the value you're passing to `new Date()` is actually a string, not a number. Convert it to a number first.

```
let d = new Date(Number(req.params.date_string));
```

Comment: Already did it, it works the same way. I suppose Express parses it automatically, otherwise it would not pass my first if-statement.

Comment: It passes the if statement because it's parsing the string as a year, not microseconds.

Comment: Did you make this change also in `res.json()`? I'm not sure why you call `new Date()` again, you can just use `test: d`.

Comment: Thanks, probably there was a mistake in how I passed the parsed string! I rewrote and it works.